# How to generate a Makefile with source in sub-directories using just one makefile

Tags: makefile

I have source in a bunch of subdirectories like:

```
src/widgets/apple.cpp
src/widgets/knob.cpp
src/tests/blend.cpp
src/ui/flash.cpp
```

In the root of the project I want to generate a single Makefile using a rule like:

```
%.o: %.cpp
   $(CC) -c $<

build/test.exe: build/widgets/apple.o build/widgets/knob.o build/tests/blend.o src/ui/flash.o
   $(LD) build/widgets/apple.o .... build/ui/flash.o -o build/test.exe
```

When I try this it does not find a rule for `build/widgets/apple.o`. Can I change something so that the `%.o: %.cpp` is used when it needs to make `build/widgets/apple.o` ?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The reason is that your rule

```
%.o: %.cpp
       ...
```

expects the .cpp file to reside in the same directory as the .o your building. Since test.exe in your case depends on build/widgets/apple.o (etc), make is expecting apple.cpp to be build/widgets/apple.cpp.

You can use VPATH to resolve this:

```
VPATH = src/widgets

BUILDDIR = build/widgets

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
      ...
```

When attempting to build "build/widgets/apple.o", make will search for apple.cpp **in VPATH**. Note that the build rule has to use special variables in order to access the actual filename make finds:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) $< -o $@
```

Where "$<" expands to the path where make located the first dependency.

Also note that this will build all the .o files in build/widgets. If you want to build the binaries in different directories, you can do something like

```
build/widgets/%.o: %.cpp
        ....

build/ui/%.o: %.cpp
        ....

build/tests/%.o: %.cpp
        ....
```

I would recommend that you use "[canned command sequences](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes)" in order to avoid repeating the actual compiler build rule:

```
define cc-command
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
endef
```

You can then have multiple rules like this:

```
build1/foo.o build1/bar.o: %.o: %.cpp
    $(cc-command)

build2/frotz.o build2/fie.o: %.o: %.cpp
    $(cc-command)
```

Comment: `VPATH` does not allow you to have different source files with the same name in different directories, which defeats the purpose of directories in the first place.

Comment: Eh, no I don't think it does. Organizing your source code in different directories has more benefits than allowing multiple source files with the same name.

Comment: I have tried to follow your solution and created targets of the form `.build/cwrapper/%.o: %.c %.cpp`. However, when I use these as dependency, e.g. `cwrapper: .build/cwrapper/%.o`, `make` complains: "No rule to make target `.build/cwrapper/%.o'". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In case somebody needed: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html

Answer (score 75):

This does the trick:

```
CC        := g++
LD        := g++

MODULES   := widgets test ui
SRC_DIR   := $(addprefix src/,$(MODULES))
BUILD_DIR := $(addprefix build/,$(MODULES))

SRC       := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.cpp))
OBJ       := $(patsubst src/%.cpp,build/%.o,$(SRC))
INCLUDES  := $(addprefix -I,$(SRC_DIR))

vpath %.cpp $(SRC_DIR)

define make-goal
$1/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $$< -o $$@
endef

.PHONY: all checkdirs clean

all: checkdirs build/test.exe

build/test.exe: $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $^ -o $@


checkdirs: $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

$(foreach bdir,$(BUILD_DIR),$(eval $(call make-goal,$(bdir))))
```

This Makefile assumes you have your include files in the source directories. Also it checks if the build directories exist, and creates them if they do not exist.

The last line is the most important. It creates the implicit rules for each build using the function `make-goal`, and it is not necessary write them one by one

You can also add automatic dependency generation, using [Tromey's way](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html)

Comment: Your use of foreach really helped me. I create a long list of C files that I generate an individual object file. Thanks!

Comment: @Manzill0 the following question has the same set of issues when dealing with multiple targets and their dependencies? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043480/make-recipe-to-prevent-rebuilding-of-non-dependent-targets#

Comment: This is really helpful, unfortunately calling mkdir everytime really slows down the build process. I haven't found a workaround for that.

Comment: I get `Makefile:34: *** missing separator.  Stop.` And 34 is that 'most important' function. It also doesn't get syntax highlighting. Only when I put a variable name and a `=` in front

Comment: Usually replacing spaces with tabs solves the `missing separator` error.

Answer (score 8):

Thing is `$@` will include the entire (relative) path to the source file which is in turn used to construct the object name (and thus its relative path)

We use:

```
#####################
# rules to build the object files
$(OBJDIR_1)/%.o: %.c
    @$(ECHO) "$< -> $@"
    @test -d $(OBJDIR_1) || mkdir -pm 775 $(OBJDIR_1)
    @test -d $(@D) || mkdir -pm 775 $(@D)
    @-$(RM) $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_1) $(ALL_FLAGS) $(ALL_DEFINES) $(ALL_INCLUDEDIRS:%=-I%) -c $< -o $@
```

This creates an object directory with name specified in `$(OBJDIR_1)`
and subdirectories according to subdirectories in source.

For example (assume objs as toplevel object directory), in Makefile:

```
widget/apple.cpp
tests/blend.cpp
```

results in following object directory:

```
objs/widget/apple.o
objs/tests/blend.o
```

Comment: @test -d $(OBJDIR_1) || mkdir -pm 775 $(OBJDIR_1) -- why do you need this line?

Answer (score 6):

This is another trick.

In main 'Makefile' define SRCDIR for each source dir and include 'makef.mk' for each value of SRCDIR.  In each source dir put file 'files.mk' with list of source files and compile options for some of them.  In main 'Makefile' one can define compile options and exclude files for each value of SRCDIR.

Makefile:

```
PRG             := prog-name

OPTIMIZE        := -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer

CFLAGS += -finline-functions-called-once
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-section,--reduce-memory-overheads,--relax


.DEFAULT_GOAL   := hex

OBJDIR          := obj

MK_DIRS         := $(OBJDIR)


SRCDIR          := .
include         makef.mk

SRCDIR := crc
CFLAGS_crc := -DCRC8_BY_TABLE -DMODBUS_CRC_BY_TABLE
ASFLAGS_crc := -DCRC8_BY_TABLE -DMODBUS_CRC_BY_TABLE
include makef.mk

################################################################

CC              := avr-gcc -mmcu=$(MCU_TARGET) -I.
OBJCOPY         := avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP         := avr-objdump

C_FLAGS         := $(CFLAGS) $(REGS) $(OPTIMIZE)
CPP_FLAGS       := $(CPPFLAGS) $(REGS) $(OPTIMIZE)
AS_FLAGS        := $(ASFLAGS)
LD_FLAGS        := $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-Map,$(OBJDIR)/$(PRG).map


C_OBJS          := $(C_SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
CPP_OBJS        := $(CPP_SRC:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
AS_OBJS         := $(AS_SRC:%.S=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

C_DEPS          := $(C_OBJS:%=%.d)
CPP_DEPS        := $(CPP_OBJS:%=%.d)
AS_DEPS         := $(AS_OBJS:%=%.d)

OBJS            := $(C_OBJS) $(CPP_OBJS) $(AS_OBJS)
DEPS            := $(C_DEPS) $(CPP_DEPS) $(AS_DEPS)


hex:  $(PRG).hex
lst:  $(PRG).lst


$(OBJDIR)/$(PRG).elf : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(LD_FLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.lst: $(OBJDIR)/%.elf
    -@rm $@ 2> /dev/nul
    $(OBJDUMP) -h -s -S $< > $@

%.hex: $(OBJDIR)/%.elf
    -@rm $@ 2> /dev/nul
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .text -j .data -O ihex $< $@


$(C_OBJS) : $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c Makefile
    $(CC) -MMD -MF $@.p.d -c $(C_FLAGS) $(C_FLAGS_$(call clear_name,$<)) $< -o $@
    @sed -e 's,.*:,SRC_FILES += ,g' < $@.p.d > $@.d
    @sed -e "\$$s/$$/ $(subst /,\/,$(dir $<))files.mk\n/" < $@.p.d >> $@.d
    @sed -e 's,^[^:]*: *,,' -e 's,^[ \t]*,,' -e 's, \\$$,,' -e 's,$$, :,' < $@.p.d >> $@.d
    -@rm -f $@.p.d

$(CPP_OBJS) : $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp Makefile
    $(CC) -MMD -MF $@.p.d -c $(CPP_FLAGS) $(CPP_FLAGS_$(call clear_name,$<)) $< -o $@
    @sed -e 's,.*:,SRC_FILES += ,g' < $@.p.d > $@.d
    @sed -e "\$$s/$$/ $(subst /,\/,$(dir $<))files.mk\n/" < $@.p.d >> $@.d
    @sed -e 's,^[^:]*: *,,' -e 's,^[ \t]*,,' -e 's, \\$$,,' -e 's,$$, :,' < $@.p.d >> $@.d
    -@rm -f $@.p.d

$(AS_OBJS) : $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.S Makefile
    $(CC) -MMD -MF $@.p.d -c $(AS_FLAGS) $(AS_FLAGS_$(call clear_name,$<)) $< -o $@
    @sed -e 's,.*:,SRC_FILES += ,g' < $@.p.d > $@.d
    @sed -e "\$$s/$$/ $(subst /,\/,$(dir $<))files.mk\n/" < $@.p.d >> $@.d
    @sed -e 's,^[^:]*: *,,' -e 's,^[ \t]*,,' -e 's, \\$$,,' -e 's,$$, :,' < $@.p.d >> $@.d
    -@rm -f $@.p.d


clean:
    -@rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/$(PRG).elf
    -@rm -rf $(PRG).lst $(OBJDIR)/$(PRG).map
    -@rm -rf $(PRG).hex $(PRG).bin $(PRG).srec
    -@rm -rf $(PRG)_eeprom.hex $(PRG)_eeprom.bin $(PRG)_eeprom.srec
    -@rm -rf $(MK_DIRS:%=%/*.o) $(MK_DIRS:%=%/*.o.d)
    -@rm -f tags cscope.out

#   -rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*
#   -rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
#   -rm $(PRG)


tag: tags
tags: $(SRC_FILES)
    if [ -e tags ] ; then ctags -u $? ; else ctags $^ ; fi
    cscope -U -b $^


# include dep. files
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEPS)
endif


# Create directory
$(shell mkdir $(MK_DIRS) 2>/dev/null)
```

makef.mk

```
SAVE_C_SRC := $(C_SRC)
SAVE_CPP_SRC := $(CPP_SRC)
SAVE_AS_SRC := $(AS_SRC)

C_SRC :=
CPP_SRC :=
AS_SRC :=


include $(SRCDIR)/files.mk
MK_DIRS += $(OBJDIR)/$(SRCDIR)


clear_name = $(subst /,_,$(1))


define rename_var
$(2)_$(call clear_name,$(SRCDIR))_$(call clear_name,$(1)) := \
    $($(subst _,,$(2))_$(call clear_name,$(SRCDIR))) $($(call clear_name,$(1)))
$(call clear_name,$(1)) :=
endef


define proc_lang

ORIGIN_SRC_FILES := $($(1)_SRC)

ifneq ($(strip $($(1)_ONLY_FILES)),)
$(1)_SRC := $(filter $($(1)_ONLY_FILES),$($(1)_SRC))
else

ifneq ($(strip $(ONLY_FILES)),)
$(1)_SRC := $(filter $(ONLY_FILES),$($(1)_SRC))
else
$(1)_SRC := $(filter-out $(EXCLUDE_FILES),$($(1)_SRC))
endif

endif

$(1)_ONLY_FILES :=
$(foreach name,$($(1)_SRC),$(eval $(call rename_var,$(name),$(1)_FLAGS)))
$(foreach name,$(ORIGIN_SRC_FILES),$(eval $(call clear_name,$(name)) :=))

endef


$(foreach lang,C CPP AS, $(eval $(call proc_lang,$(lang))))


EXCLUDE_FILES :=
ONLY_FILES :=


SAVE_C_SRC += $(C_SRC:%=$(SRCDIR)/%)
SAVE_CPP_SRC += $(CPP_SRC:%=$(SRCDIR)/%)
SAVE_AS_SRC += $(AS_SRC:%=$(SRCDIR)/%)

C_SRC := $(SAVE_C_SRC)
CPP_SRC := $(SAVE_CPP_SRC)
AS_SRC := $(SAVE_AS_SRC)
```

./files.mk

```
C_SRC   := main.c
CPP_SRC :=
AS_SRC  := timer.S

main.c += -DDEBUG
```

./crc/files.mk

```
C_SRC    := byte-modbus-crc.c byte-crc8.c
AS_SRC   := modbus-crc.S crc8.S modbus-crc-table.S crc8-table.S

byte-modbus-crc.c += --std=gnu99
byte-crc8.c       += --std=gnu99
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution, inspired from Beta's answer. It's simpler than the other proposed solutions

I have a project with several C files, stored in many subdirectories.
For example:

```
src/lib.c
src/aa/a1.c
src/aa/a2.c
src/bb/b1.c
src/cc/c1.c
```

Here is my Makefile (in the `src/` directory):

```
# make       -> compile the shared library "libfoo.so"
# make clean -> remove the library file and all object files (.o)
# make all   -> clean and compile
SONAME  = libfoo.so
SRC     = lib.c   \
          aa/a1.c \
          aa/a2.c \
          bb/b1.c \
          cc/c1.c
# compilation options
CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -W -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wbad-function-cast -fPIC
# linking options
LDFLAGS = -shared -Wl,-soname,$(SONAME)

# how to compile individual object files
OBJS    = $(SRC:.c=.o)
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: all clean

# library compilation
$(SONAME): $(OBJS) $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(SONAME)

# cleaning rule
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(SONAME) *~

# additional rule
all: clean lib
```

This example works fine for a shared library, and it should be very easy to adapt for any compilation process.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it without painful manipulation or multiple command sequences:

```
build/%.o: src/%.cpp
src/%.o: src/%.cpp
%.o:
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

build/test.exe: build/widgets/apple.o build/widgets/knob.o build/tests/blend.o src/ui/flash.o
    $(LD) $^ -o $@
```

JasperE has explained why "%.o: %.cpp" won't work; this version has one pattern rule (%.o:) with commands and no prereqs, and two pattern rules (build/%.o: and src/%.o:) with prereqs and no commands. (Note that I put in the src/%.o rule to deal with src/ui/flash.o, assuming that wasn't a typo for build/ui/flash.o, so if you don't need it you can leave it out.)

build/test.exe needs build/widgets/apple.o,
build/widgets/apple.o looks like build/%.o, so it needs src/%.cpp (in this case src/widgets/apple.cpp),
build/widgets/apple.o also looks like %.o, so it executes the CC command and uses the prereqs it just found (namely src/widgets/apple.cpp) to build the target (build/widgets/apple.o)

Comment: This breaks, because your `%.o:` rule does not have prerequisites, yet refers to them via `$<` (which is therefore empty). "No input files", sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you create a Makefile in each subdirectory, and write in the top-level Makefile to call make in the subdirectories.

[This page](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) may help.

Comment: This is commonly done, but is full of problems.  The main one is that no one make process knows about all of the dependencies, so things like -j2 on multicore systems won't work.  See http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf

Comment: Keith's reference is to an excellent paper called 'Recursive Make Considered Harmful'.  This is a contribution to the series of articles starting with Dijkstra's 'Go To Considered Harmful' letter, and culminating in "'Considered Harmful' Considered Harmful".

Comment: It's done usually because people don't understand how to write Makefiles. One Makefile per directory sucks.