# Makefile error when compiling with gfortran on Mac OS

Tags: macos, linker, makefile, ld, gfortran

I run Mac OS X lion with the latest Xcode (4.3):

```
gfortran --version # -> GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.6.1
gcc --version # -> i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658)
```

My makefile gives an error:

```
gfortran temp/modules.o temp/testModules.o temp/mathFunctions.o temp/functionTest.o -o arenatest
ld: duplicate symbol ___rng_MOD_uni in temp/testModules.o and temp/modules.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [arenatest] Error 1
```

I don't understand what the reason is, so I tried writing a build script that does the same thing, and surprisingly it works wonders. I want to have a makefile and NOT a script, so could anyone spot the difference? I am completely out of ideas.

I know that there is a funky loop-replacement script for generating the .o objects in the right subdirectories. The build/compile-commands seem to match perfectly however. If there is a cleverer way of doing this, I'm open for suggestions.

Script:

```
echo remove old files
rm *.mod
rm *.o
rm -rf temp
rm arenatest

echo create directories and compile:
mkdir -p temp
gfortran -cpp -c ../modules/modules.f90 -o temp/modules.o -J../buildtest -I../buildtest
gfortran -cpp -c ../modules/mathFunctions.f90 -o temp/mathFunctions.o -J../buildtest -I../buildtest
gfortran -cpp -c testModules.f90 -o temp/testModules.o -J../buildtest -I../buildtest
gfortran -cpp -c functionTest.f90 -o temp/functionTest.o -J../buildtest -I../buildtest

echo do linking: gfortran -cpp temp/modules.o temp/testModules.o temp/mathFunctions.o temp/functionTest.o -o arenatest
gfortran temp/modules.o temp/testModules.o temp/mathFunctions.o temp/functionTest.o -o arenatest

echo DONE!
```

makefile:

```
PROGRAM = arenatest
BUILDDIR = temp
FC = gfortran
SRC = ../modules/modules.f90 ../modules/mathFunctions.f90 testModules.f90 functionTest.f90
OBJ = $(SRC:.f90=.o)
OBJECTS = $(foreach var, $(OBJ), $(BUILDDIR)/$(lastword $(subst /, , $(var))) )
FLAGS =-J../buildtest -I../buildtest


all: buildtest

buildtest: $(PROGRAM)

build_message:
    @echo
    @echo sources:
    @echo $(SRC)
    @echo objects:
    @echo $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    rm -rf temp
    rm arenatest
    rm *.mod
    rm *.o


mkdir:
    @echo create directories and compile:
    mkdir -p temp

# 
# gfortran -cpp -c ../modules/modules.f90 -o temp/modules.o -J../buildtest -I../buildtest
# gfortran -cpp -c ../modules/mathFunctions.f90 -o temp/mathFunctions.o -J../buildtest -I../buildtest
# gfortran -cpp -c testModules.f90 -o temp/testModules.o -J../buildtest -I../buildtest
# gfortran -cpp -c functionTest.f90 -o temp/functionTest.o -J../buildtest -I../buildtest
# 
$(OBJECTS) : $(SRC) | mkdir
    $(FC) -c $(FLAGS) $< -o $@
# link: #echo do linking: gfortran -cpp temp/modules.o temp/testModules.o temp/mathFunctions.o temp/functionTest.o -o arenatest
$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECTS) | build_message
    $(FC) $(FLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(PROGRAM)

#echo DONE!
```

Comment: Make should echo all the commands it's running.  Just take a look at its output, and make sure all the compiler invocations are exactly as you expect.

Comment: It looks solid. It is just beyond me why it would work typing it into the command line and not by running make. I'll double check all the invocations this afternoon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recipe for compiling the object files is wrong. After expansion of variables it will look like this:

```
temp/modules.o temp/mathFunctions.o temp/testModules.o temp/functionTest.o: ../modules/modules.f90 ../modules/mathFunctions.f90 testModules.f90 functionTest.f90 | mkdir
    $(FC) -c $(FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Effectively, this means that each object file depends on all source files. Furthermore, each invocation of this recipe will set the automatic variable `$<` to the first one in this list of source files. This will have as a consequence that all object files are being compiled from the same single source file (and thus will of course all have definitions for the same symbols).

Comment: That explains it! So how do I fix it? This doesn't seem to work: `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : %.f90 | mkdir
 $(FC) $(FLAGS) $< -o $@`

Comment: Nevermind, I have an issue with subdirectories, I'm finding a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231229/how-to-generate-a-makefile-with-source-in-sub-directories-using-just-one-makefil

Comment: Easiest solution? Stick to [Paul's Third Rule of Makefiles](http://mad-scientist.net/make/rules.html): don't use the `temp` directory, but build object files in the current working directory. Combined with `vpath` to locate the source files, you can then use a simple pattern rule, like `%.o: %.f90`, and marvel over how much simpler and easier to understand/maintain your Makefile has become.