# How to create proper makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have problem with my makefile. Tree of my project looks as follow:

- makefile/ makefile
- source/ main.cpp
- includes/ first.hpp,

and i have following makefile:

```
program.o: main.o

      g++ -o program main.o

main.o: /home/project/source/main.cpp, /home/project/include/first.hpp

      g++ -c /home/project/source/main.cpp /home/project/include/first.hpp
```

How i can create makefile without paths? I mean something like this:

```
program.o: main.o

       g++ -o program main.o

main.o: main.cpp, first.hpp

     g++ -c main.cpp first.hpp
```

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/231229/1758762

Answer (score 1):

[Make Tutorial: How-To Write A Makefile](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile)

And here's a [generic makefile](http://pastebin.com/PCk0gNtE) I wrote which handles dependency generation.  It's for C, but can be converted to C++ trivially.

Answer (score 0):

Make is pretty smart and has a number of built-in rules already.  [Get to know](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) these rules and the predefined macros like CXX, CFLAGS, LDFLAGS, etc.  Here's about the simplest Makefile that should build your program:

```
program: main.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<
main.o: main.cpp first.hpp
```