# How to write a single makefile, c files are in src and h files are in inc folder?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write a makefile which should pick the sources from src/ and headers from inc/

**~/Linuz/src: 1.c, 2.c, 3.c ...**

**~/Linuz/inc: abc.h, dyz.h**

Please help me to create a makefile which should be available at

**~/Linuz/some_other_dir/Makefile**

PS: Trying to compile it for my linux machine.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231229/how-to-generate-a-makefile-with-source-in-sub-directories-using-just-one-makefil

Comment: @user2050283: tried with

TOP_DIR = /Linuz/
SRC_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)/src
INC_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)/inc
TEST_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)/test

CFLAGS= -I$(INC_DIR)
VPATH= -I$(SRC_DIR)

testapp: CFLAGS:.o

Please suggest me, if I am wrong.
prettymuch new to makefile architecture.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
all: my_program

%.o: ../src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I../inc/ -c -o $@ $^

my_program: 1.o 2.o 3.o 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o my_program
```

If you put your Makefile in the **~/Linuz/some_other_dir/**, the following rule

```
%.o: ../src/%.c
```

will get the c files from the `../src/` folder (**~/Linuz/src/**) and create the object (*.o) files in the same folder of the Makefile.

The `-I../inc/` option means that the makefile canl get a header files from the `../inc/` folder (**~/Linuz/inc/**).

The `my_program: 1.o 2.o 3.o` rule means that the makefile will create the binary in the same directory of Makefile from the object files `1.o` and `2.o` and `3.o`

From the [make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables):

> **$^**    The names of all the prerequisites, with spaces between them.
>   For prerequisites which are archive members, only the member named is
>   used (see Archives). A target has only one prerequisite on each other
>   file it depends on, no matter how many times each file is listed as a
>   prerequisite. So if you list a prerequisite more than once for a
>   target, the value of $^ contains just one copy of the name. This list
>   does not contain any of the order-only prerequisites; for those see
>   the `$|' variable, below.
>
> **$@**  The file name of the target of the rule. If the target is an
>   archive member, then ‘$@’ is the name of the archive file. In a
>   pattern rule that has multiple targets (see Introduction to Pattern
>   Rules), ‘$@’ is the name of whichever target caused the rule's recipe
>   to be run.

Comment: If you put some words in to explain why this works, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @Mohamed KALLEL, I appreciate your writeups !! would you like to brief what is $@ and $^ here ?

Comment: Thank you Mohamed KALLEL
Appreciate your notes !!