# How to write a makefile to generate object files and executable in different directory?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

Now to proceed further I need to change the presentation of existing Makefile.

Presently I am using:

```
~/Linuz/src: 1.c, 2.c, 3.c ...

~/Linuz/inc: abc.h, xyz.h
```

and makefile is in: `~/Linuz/some_other_dir/`

But need to change the structure.

1. Want to create a library from (`~/Linuz/src/` and `~/linuz/inc`)
2. Library will be used to get executable. Application source files(.c files) are in `~/Linuz/app/`
3. `~/Linuz/bin/` should be created during compilation to store all the object files and executable file.

Any suggestions ??

**My makefile looks like this:**

```
all: Library.a

%.o: ../src/%.c

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I../inc/ -c -o $@ $^

Library.a:  $(SRC_DIR)/1.c $(SRC_DIR)/2.c $(SRC_DIR)/3.c $(SRC_DIR)/4.c $(SRC_DIR)/5.c

    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

all: prog

%.o: ./*.c

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -ILibrary.a -c -o $@ $^


prog:   $(APP_DIR)/app1.c $(APP_DIR)/app2.c $(APP_DIR)/app3.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o my_program
```

Comment: @linuz put it in your question

Comment: @Linuz: Ok, can you edit your question to include that, and also an explanation of what problems you had with it?

Comment: Ok. I give up (or I'm totally reading this (`-ILibrary.a`) wrong): Gotta ask. Why is your library file being specified as an additional *include path* ?? Why do you have multiple `all:` targets in this file? Why is your prog not dependent on the library? In short, perhaps some time on the [gnu-make doc site](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) will do some good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let assume that your code architecture looks like that:

```
└── linuz
    ├── app
    │   ├── app1.c
    │   ├── app2.c
    │   └── app3.c
    ├── bin
    ├── inc
    │   └── any.h
    ├── some_other_dir
    │   └── Makefile
    └── src
        ├── 1.c
        ├── 2.c
        └── 3.c
```

So your Makefile could be:

```
all: ../bin/libmy_lib.a ../bin/my_program


../bin/my_lib_%.o: ../src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I../inc -c -o $@ $^

../bin/libmy_lib.a: ../bin/my_lib_1.o ../bin/my_lib_2.o  ../bin/my_lib_3.o
    ar rcs $@ $^

../bin/my_app_%.o: ../app/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I../inc -c -o $@ $^

../bin/my_program: ../bin/my_app_app1.o ../bin/my_app_app2.o  ../bin/my_app_app3.o ../bin/libmy_lib.a
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -L../bin/ -lmy_lib -o $@ $^


clean:
    rm -f ../bin/*.o ../bin/libmy_lib.a ../bin/my_program
```

For the explanation, refer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475310/how-to-write-a-single-makefile-c-files-are-in-src-and-h-files-are-in-inc-folder)

Comment: Thank you Mohamed KALLEL !!

helped your suggestions :)