# Header file path in a C file

Tags: c, linux, makefile

My project is organised in a folder

```
myproj/
       src/
           main.c
       inc/
           main.h
       makefile
```

I have in my C files

```
 #include <main.h>
```

and in my makefile i have

```
INCLUDE = /inc
SOURCE = src/

compile:
    $(CC) -I$(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCPATH)main.c -o myapp $(LIBS)

myapp: 
    $(CC) -I$(INCLUDE) $(FLG_LIB) -o myapp main.c
```

but i get - fatal error: No such file or directory.

i also tried "main.h", but of no use.

Comment: `#include "../inc/main.h"`?

Comment: maybe this is silly, but maybe a mismatch between `SOURCE` and `SRCPATH`?

Comment: Just to understand the difference between `#include <...>` and `#include "..."`, you may look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21594/4384927)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231229/how-to-generate-a-makefile-with-source-in-sub-directories-using-just-one-makefil)

Comment: `#include <main.h>` suggests that the compiler/linker should look for this file in the library path, while `#include "main.h"` suggests it should look in your local source code. So always use the latter form for your own files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it again by changing `'INCLUDE=/inc'` to `'INCLUDE=inc/'` (notice:trim the blank character `' '` before and after the `'='`).

BTW,Using `#include ""` instead of `#include <>` in your case,because the first usage let the compiler find the header file firstly from local path then from the system path,the latter one(with `<>`) is the opposite.