# Using same namespace in C++ for two classes declared and defined in separate files

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying to declare two classes *C1* and *C2* in files *nstest1.h* and *nstest2.h* which are defined in files *nstest1.cpp* and *nstest2.cpp* respectively. Both the classes are defined under same namespace.

Following are the files :

```
//nstest1.h
namespace Mine{
    class C1{
        public:
        void callme();
    };
}

//nstest2.h
namespace Mine {
    class C2 {
        public:
            void callme();
    };
}

//nstest1.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "nstest1.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Mine;

void Mine::C1::callme(){
    std::cout << "Please call me " << std::endl;
}

//nstest2.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "nstest2.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Mine;

void Mine::C2::callme(){
    std::cout << "Please call me too" << std::endl ;
}
```

Following file tries to use this classes using namespace *Mine*.

```
//nstest.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "nstest1.h"
#include "nstest2.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Mine;

int main(){
    Mine::C1 c1;
    Mine::C2 c2;
    c1.callme();
    c2.callme();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile using command "g++ nstest.cpp", I get following error :

```
/tmp/cc2y4zc6.o: In function `main':
nstest.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `Mine::C1::callme()'
nstest.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `Mine::C2::callme()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If the definitions are moved to the declaration files (nstest1.h and nstest2.h), it works fine. Not sure whats happening here. Am I missing something ?
Thanks in advance :) .

Comment: Compile with `g++ nstest1.cpp nstest2.cpp nstest.cpp`. You need to compile all source files.

Comment: Thanks :).
It works fine for this case. But is it possible to avoid compiling declarations and definitions every-time ?

Comment: The only way would be to include the definition inside the header file. The compiler needs to see the implementation. You can also use a makefile to automatically compile source files, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231229/how-to-generate-a-makefile-with-source-in-sub-directories-using-just-one-makefil/2484343#2484343), then all you have to do is call `make` to compile everything.

Comment: You can make a library from your definitions and link to it rather than compiling it every time. Or even just link to the `.o` files.

Comment: Thanks James :)
It seems writing a makefile will be helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the other .cpp files when building the program.

Option 1: Compile all the files and build the executable in one command

```
g++ nstest.cpp nstest1.cpp nstest2.cpp -o nstest
```

Option 2: Compile each file separately and then build the executable after that

```
g++ -c nstext1.cpp
g++ -c nstest2.cpp
g++ -c nstest.cpp
g++ nstest.o nstest1.o nstext2.o -o nstest
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem happens at link time. Your headers are fine. But you should compile the other cpp files aswell.