# Makefile not compiling all C files in directory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, mingw

Iam working with gcc and MinGW on a Windows platform. I have a directory containing two *.c files:
main.c and funcs.c

I am using the following makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c
LDFLAGS= 
SOURCEDIR = src
BUILDDIR = build
SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
LIBRARIES=-L/mingw64/lib
INC= -I./include
EXECUTABLE=testLink
VPATH = src include build

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBRARIES)  -o ./dist/$@

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Which should take the *.c files and generate *.o files with the same name. However I get the following output on make -

```
$ make
gcc -I./include -c src/funcs.c -o build/funcs.o
gcc -I./include -c src/funcs.c -o build/main.o
gcc  build/funcs.o build/main.o -L/mingw64/lib  -o ./dist/testLink
```

followed of course by a bunch of multiple definition errors. As you can see from the first two lines it is taking the same *.c file and compiling it twice into two different *.o files.

I am new to makefiles but I assume it is something wrong with my $(OBJECTS) rule and I'm pretty sure it's the $< which is causing the problem. I'm trying to create a generic makefile which will always work on my projects which have the same directory structure and take .c files turn them into .o files and link. Am I going about this entirely the wrong way or is there a simple fix to my makefile?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

expands to:

```
funcs.o main.c: funcs.c main.c
    $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

which is equivalent to:

```
funcs.o: funcs.c main.c
    $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

main.o: funcs.c main.c
    $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

`$<` refers to the first dependency (funcs.c) so your Makefile is trying to generate both funcs.o and main.o from the same source.

You just want a generic rule using `%` wildcard matching:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html

Answer (score 2):

Jeff pointed the mistake in his answer (all objects depend on all sources: that isn't a generic compilation rule for c sources).

However, the generic rule must have source & object paths. To sum it up, just replace

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

by

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

(as explained in [How to generate a Makefile with source in sub-directories using just one makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231229/how-to-generate-a-makefile-with-source-in-sub-directories-using-just-one-makefil))

note that this kind of dependency test doesn't take included `.h` files into account, so it's only intended for first builds. Modifying `.h` files afterwards doesn't trigger a compilation since the header files are not listed as dependencies.